# Result or purpose interpretation

Tags: grammar

I have looked at a few grammar books for explanations of the possible interpretations of "so-that" dependent clauses and here are two examples that the authors used to illustrate a "purpose" interpretation of these clauses:

> We're advertising the course so that everyone will know about it. (the
>   author notes that a "result" interpretation is possible.)
>
> I have lit the fire so that the house will be warm when they return.
>   (no notes about a possible "result" interpretation.)

I cannot understand either of the "so-that" clauses in the sentences above as having the meaning of "purpose". In either case I read them as expressing the result of what is stated in the introductory clause: ..and as a result the house will be warm.. and as a result everyone will know about it.

For the "purpose" reading, I'd expect the simple present "so that everyone knows about it" and "so that the house is warm ..".

Am I wrong (and how much wrong am I) that the salient (if not only) interpretation of these sentences is "resultative"?

Comment: I don't see why a "result" and a "purpose" reading are different or suggest a different verb in the dependent clause.  Both the purpose and the result of the advertising are to let people know about it (or ensure that they will know in the future.  Same with fire.

Comment: 'We're advertising the course so that everyone will know about it.' = 'We're advertising the course to make sure that everyone will know about it.' Purpose. That's why 'they' are advertising the course. This is the default reading. /  'The rain was triple the average for the year, so that the level of water in the lake became dangerously high' must have a purely resultative interpretation, as there's no volitional agent involved. / Sometimes, either reading may be available.

Comment: Thank you for the answers both :) Edwin, I had in mind situations which involve a volitional agent in the main clause, and its relation with the result expressed in the "so that" clause. This result/consequence may or may not be understood as the sole, intended purpose of the action in the main clause. In these particular examples it may seem so (although we may have lit the fire with the primary purpose of cooking for example). The purpose "so that" is synonymous with "in order to", but any attending, unintended consequence is not.

Comment: For example, "Pope Francis is selling his Harley Davidson motorbikes in order to/ so that he can raise money for charity." ("so that" introduces the purpose of selling motorbikes)
Pope Francis is selling his Harley Davidson motorbikes so that (for the time being ) he will be without a vehicle to get around. ("so that" introduces an attending consequence which is not a purpose of selling motorbikes).

Comment: This usage is illustrated in this example: I’ll post the CD today so that you get it by the weekend. (or … so that you will get it …)  from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so-that-or-in-order-that
I use the simple present tense instead of "will" in similar sentences, especially with stative verbs. I was wondering what is the general preference among speakers regarding the use of "will" vs simple present in "so that" clauses.

Answer (score 1):

In a grammatical context, ***Purpose*** and ***Result*** are technical terms and don't really contrast.

1. *Purpose* has to do with human intentions, in the results of some action they undertake.
2. *Result* has to do with causation.
3. The *so that* construction refers to the intention of a human agent to bring about some result.

   - *We're advertising it **so (that) everyone will know about it**.*
     (obviously not a real result -- who ever achieves 100% ad placement, let alone takeup?)
   - *I've lit the fire **so the house will be warm when they return**.*
     (a reasonable expectation -- note the predictive *will* -- but not guaranteed)
   - *He pulled down his hat **so (that) they couldn't identify him**.*
     (that was his intended result, but it may or may not have been successful)

Various people use various terms for these constructions, depending on their preferences, and what they learned in grammar school. Examples are more useful in discussing constructions than technical terms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer John Lawler! If I have understood you correctly (and I may easily have not :) I'll have to disagree that the terms of "purpose" and "result" do not contrast in "so that" clauses. The distinction is pretty important to make for non-native speakers like me. Point 3 "The so that construction refers to the intention of a human agent to bring about some result" must be an inaccurate generalization of the use of "so that" clauses. I could google a plenty of examples where "so that" clause doesn't express a result intended by the human agent in the main clause.

Comment: Examples are always better than descriptions, and promises of examples are not examples.

Comment: I agree John :) Here's a passage from Quirk's grammar relating the disambiguation between "result" and "purpose" introduced by a "so that" clause: "The chief semantic difference is that result clauses are factual rather than putative: both express result, but in the result clause the result is
achieved, whereas in the purpose clause it is yet to be achieved - it is a
desired or aimed-at result. Hence finite clauses of result do not require a
modal auxiliary:
We paid him immediately, so that he left contented , [result] 
We paid him immediately so that he would leave contented. [purpose] "

Comment: I intuitively understand the difference between "result" and "purpose" "so that" clauses along these lines: when I think of "so that" in terms of purpose I expect that this clause has a meaning of something that yet needs to be achieved, while "result so that" indicates something already achieved. The problem for me arises when the main clause is in the present tense which triggers the use of "will" or the simple present tense verb in the "purpose" "so that" clause. For some reason "will" in the examples I provided in OP feels "factual" rather than "putative", to use the terms from Quirk.

Comment: Now, I cannot explain either why I don't like "will" in "purpose" "so that" clauses, in none of the examples I provided (including the one from CALD, where it is provided as an alternative wording : I’ll post the CD today so that you get it by the weekend. (or … so that you WILL get it …), nor can I explain why the simple present sounds fine ( where there is no modal verb to indicate non-factuality e.g We are planning to give him notice to leave after his 4th month so that he leaves after the 6th month minimum period.).

Comment: The contrast (and the problem of disambiguating the meanings of purpose and result) is made additionally important when negation comes into play: I quit my job so that I could take care of my mother. vs I quit my job so that I couldn't take care of my mother (purpose vs result interpretations hinge on the clause type). Many speakers seem to resolve this problem by keeping "so that" for "purpose" clauses and "so" for "result" ones.
Examples of "result" "so that" clauses with human/agentive subject : He went on arguing in a nasty tone, so that in the end I lost my patience.

Comment: @Rejlan Givens 'I'll have to disagree that the terms of "purpose" and "result" do not contrast in "so that" clauses.' This is because you're using the default everyday definitions of _purpose_ and _result_, which don't exactly match (and in fact in places contradict) the precisionist definitions John refers to.